# print and check actual value of Javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm currently analyzing a datatable constructor function in Javascript.

I have a var named field getting passed that holds all of the values for a checkbox element.

So it further gets broken down into separate vars for the element.

```
var field_value = field.value;
var field_name = field.name;
//The field_hidden is a passed data field to determine if I should hide checkbox. 
var field_hidden = field.hidden;
```

then gets returned as a checkbox element.

```
return '<input type="checkbox"' + field_name + htmlEncode(field_value) + field_checked+' >';
```

I want to add some additional functionality to this element constructor, but the value getting printed to my console is this: `javascript constructor {jobid}`

Now I know that `{jobid}` is my data field. That is correct, but how do I get that actual value to check if it exists?

I want to make my checkboxes hidden depending on if that field is null.

Pasted below is a snippet of the js datatable constructor for further context.

I can't seem to Google or search the right combo to find what answers I need, and so I come here for some wisdom on the subject. Thank you.

I have a feeling that perhaps this constructor is getting processed somewhere down stream, so I can't manipulate it, but I'm honestly not sure.

```
{
          targets: 'dt-checkbox',
          type: 'num',
          orderDataType: 'dom-checkbox',
          render: {
            display: function(data, type, row, meta) {
              // Changes cell to checkbox given field_value and field_name

              var opts = meta.settings.aoColumns[meta.col].dt_opts;
              if(typeof opts === 'undefined') {
                opts = meta.settings.aoColumns[meta.col].dt_opts = {};
              }
              var field = opts.field
              if(typeof field === 'undefined') {
                field = opts.field = {};
              }

              

              var field_value = field.value;
              var field_name = field.name;
              var field_checked = field.checked;
//The field_hidden is a passed data field to determine if I should hide checkbox. 
              var field_hidden = field.hidden;

              console.log("This is the field_hidden", field_hidden);

              // Resolve fieldnames to values
              var re = /^\{(.+)\}$/;
              if(typeof(field_value) !== 'undefined' && field_value !== null) {
                var match = field_value.match(re);
                if(match) {
                  var field_value_fieldname = match[1];
                  field_value = row[field_value_fieldname];
                }
                field_value = ' value="' + field_value + '"';
              }
              if(typeof(field_name) !== 'undefined' && field_name !== null) {
                var match = field_name.match(re);
                if(match) {
                  var field_name_fieldname = match[1];
                  field_name = row[field_name_fieldname];
                }
                field_name = ' name="' + field_name + '"';
              }
              if(typeof(field_checked) !== 'undefined' && field_checked !== null) {
                var match = field_checked.match(re);
                if(match) {
                  var field_checked_fieldname = match[1];
                  field_checked = row[field_checked_fieldname]? 1:0;
                }
                field_checked = field_checked && field_checked != '0'? ' checked="checked"' : '';
              }
//This is where I was trying to see if this is a var or object, and if it is empty. No luck. 
              if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(field_hidden))
              {
                return '<input type="checkbox"' + field_name + htmlEncode(field_value) + field_checked+' >';
              }
              else
              {
                return '<input type="checkbox"' + field_name + htmlEncode(field_value) + field_checked+' hidden >';
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

Comment: PSA: It's 2023 and it's time to learn about `let`, `const` and [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: That log message indicates that `field.hidden` is a class constructor function, not a value. You need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint of Barmar above, I was able to extract the value I wanted from the field constructor.

Using the code that was already built in this function, I was able to make my own conditional to get the `hidden` value I was passing.

```
 var re = /^\{(.+)\}$/;
              if(typeof(field_hidden) !== 'undefined' && field_hidden !== null) {
                var match = field_hidden.match(re);
                if(match) {
                  var field_hidden_fieldname = match[1];
                  field_hidden = row[field_hidden_fieldname];
                }
                field_hidden = ' field ="' + field_hidden + '"';
                console.log("This is the field_hidden after decoding",field_hidden);
              }
```

PSA: Some users are working with code bases they didn't write, and don't have time to build from scratch.